# Proving the binomial identity $\sum_{j=0}^k {n \choose j}\cdot {m \choose k-j}={n+m \choose k}$ when $n,m$ are negative integers

Tags: combinatorics, random-variables, binomial-coefficients

What I'm really interested in is the identity:
$$\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^k {j+r-1 \choose j}\cdot {k-j +s-1 \choose k-j}={k+r+s-1 \choose k}$$

It arises in the proof of the convolution formula of two negative binomial Random Variables, for example.

What I know is the identity:$\displaystyle { j+r-1 \choose j} = {-r \choose j} (-1)^j $

Hence what I need to show is $$ \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^k {-r \choose j} \cdot {-s \choose k-j}={-r-s \choose k}  $$ aka the  binomial convolution formula for $m = -r, n = -s$ when $s$ and $r$ are positive intergers.

How do I do that?

Comment: [Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer based upon *generating functions*. It is convenient  to use the *coefficient of* operator  $[z^n]$ to  denote the coefficient of  $z^n$  in  a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^k}&\color{blue}{\binom{j+r-1}{j}\binom{k-j+s-1}{k-j}}\\
> &=\sum_{=0}^k\binom{-r}{j}(-1)^j\binom{-s}{k-j}(-1)^{k-j}\\
> &=(-1)^k\sum_{j=0}^\infty[z^j](1+z)^{-r}[u^{k-j}](1+u)^{-s}\tag{1}\\
> &=(-1)^k[u^k](1+u)^{-s}\sum_{j=0}^\infty u^j[z^j](1+z)^{-r}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^k[u^k](1+u)^{-s}(1+u)^{-r}\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^k[u^k](1+u)^{-r-s}\\
> &=(-1)^k\binom{-r-s}{k}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\binom{k+r+s-1}{k}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu.E2.80.93Vandermonde_identity)* follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice and set the upper limit of the series to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p}]z^qA(z)=[z^{p-q}]A(z)$.
- In (3) we apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $u=z$
  \begin{align*}
  A(u)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j u^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty u^j [z^j]A(z)
  \end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

For instance, you can use **induction on $n$** to show that if $p_{n}(x)$ is the polynomial:
$$p_{0}(x)=1$$
$$p_{n}(x)=(x)_n=x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1),\ \text{for each}\ n\geq 1$$

then

$$p_{n}(x+y)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}p_{k}(x)p_{n-k}(y)$$

> **Your identity is equivalent to the one above.**

Recall that if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x$ is a variable you can write:

$${x\choose n}=\frac{(x)_{n}}{n!}$$

The falling factorial is a family of **polynomials of binomial type** like the fmailies $f_{n}(x)=x^n$, $g_{n}(x)=x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)$, Abel polynomials, Touchard polynomials.